# Disable network access for specific program on specific network

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I use my phone as a WiFi hotspot with my Windows laptop. On this laptop I use the Dropbox application to sync it automatically, but the syncing can use a lot of data and my data plan only gives me 3 GB.

I have searched for a program that can disable network access for specific applications, like Windows Firewall, but with the added functionality of specifying settings for different networks. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anything like it, does anyone here know about a program that could help me?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

Windows Firewall doesn't have different settings for different networks *per se*, but you can use the different location types to serve your needs.

When using your phone as a WiFi hotspot, place your network into the Private (i.e. Work or Home) profile and everything else into the Public profile (or vice versa).  Then define firewall rules that allow or block specific programs and enable/disable those rules for each network type.  That way, you can block DropBox when you're on your phone but allow it everywhere else.

Windows firewall will remember those networks in the future when you connect to them, so you don't even have to manage it going forward.  Just define it one time and you're done.